# using create! when accepts_nested_attributes is enabled

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using two similar ways to create a record with nested attributes.

First way

```
m = Macrocycle.create!({"name"=>"sdfasdf", "description"=>"rt3t", 
                        "mesocycles_attributes"=>[{"name"=>"34fervaav", "_destroy"=>"false", "description"=>"asdfadf", "phase_number"=>"1", "workout_days_attributes"=>{"new_1332120641337"=>{"day"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}]})
 => #<Macrocycle id: 37, name: "sdfasdf", description: "rt3t", created_at: "2012-03-19 01:57:05", updated_at: "2012-03-19 01:57:05"> 
 1.9.3p125 :047 > m.mesocycles[0]                                                                                                                                               
 => #<Mesocycle id: 30, name: "34fervaav", created_at: "2012-03-19 01:57:05", updated_at:  "2012-03-19 01:57:05", description: "asdfadf", macrocycle_id: 37, phase_number: 1>
1.9.3p125 :048 > m.mesocycles[0].workout_days
 => [#<WorkoutDay id: 2, day: 1, created_at: "2012-03-19 01:57:05", updated_at: "2012-03-19   01:57:05", mesocycle_id: 30>]
```

As you can see, both mesocycles and workout_days are being created correctly. But if I use this way (instead of using array for child_attributes, using a hash with unique key for each child):

```
m = Macrocycle.create!({"name"=>"sdfasdf", "description"=>"rt3t",  "mesocycles_attributes"=>{"new_1332120631785"=>{"name"=>"34fervaav", "_destroy"=>"false", "description"=>"asdfadf", "phase_number"=>"1"}, "workout_days_attributes"=>{"new_1332120641337"=>{"day"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}})
 => #<Macrocycle id: 38, name: "sdfasdf", description: "rt3t", created_at: "2012-03-19 02:15:39", updated_at: "2012-03-19 02:15:39"> 
1.9.3p125 :052 > m.mesocycles[0]
 => #<Mesocycle id: 31, name: "34fervaav", created_at: "2012-03-19 02:15:39", updated_at: "2012-03-19 02:15:39", description: "asdfadf", macrocycle_id: 38, phase_number: 1> 
 1.9.3p125 :051 > m.mesocycles[0].workout_days                             
 => []
```

workout_days is not being created properly. However mesocycles is being created correctly.

Can't figure out for the life of me why this is happening? Is it something silly that I'm missing? The reason I ask is that I'm using ryanb's nested_form gem to create a record in my database, and nested_form uses the second way. In fact, I just used the params hash directly in my console example above.

It seems like using the hash with a unique key for each child works as far as one level down in the nest.

Update:

Association code:

Macrocycle Model:

```
class Macrocycle < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :name, :description, :mesocycles_attributes
  has_many :mesocycles, :dependent => :destroy  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :mesocycles, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Mesocycle Model:

```
class Mesocycle < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :name, :phase_number, :description, :workout_days_attributes
  belongs_to :macrocycle
  #default_scope :order => 'mesocycles.phase_number ASC'
  has_many :workout_days, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_days, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Workout Days Model:

```
class WorkoutDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :day, :blocks_attributes
  belongs_to :mesocycle
  has_many :blocks, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :blocks#, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Comment: Post your `Association` code from your models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On B your Hashes are closing before your `workoutday` is included.

```
m = Macrocycle.create!({"name"=>"sdfasdf", "description"=>"rt3t",  "mesocycles_attributes"=>{"new_1332120631785"=>{"name"=>"34fervaav", "_destroy"=>"false", "description"=>"asdfadf", "phase_number"=>"1", "workout_days_attributes"=>{"new_1332120641337"=>{"day"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}})
```

This is kinda cryptic so sorry but I think this should provide some help